# how to compare 2 strings

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have two strings initialised with using nsstring *name1,*name2...
how to compare these

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if([name1 isEqualToString:name2]){
    NSLog("These are the same name");
}
```

The best place for API features like this is the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)